# Proxypass socket io on Apache Server on Ubuntu

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache, ubuntu, socket.io

I'm trying to deploy node js socket.io project from [official sample](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/examples/chat) in my server (Ubuntu with Apache 2 Server)

This is my proxy setting in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`

```
ProxyPass /ChatSocket http://localhost:3000
ProxyPass /socket.io http://localhost:3000/socket.io
ProxyPass /socket.io ws://localhost:3000/socket.io
```

But when I try to access my web server through the dns, I can't connect to the socket.

I got this error in my browser console

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://example.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=HgU6py-fCl1GFrdsAAAK' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

Maybe because the url http://example.com/socket.io is conflicting with ws://example.com/socket.io

How can I use the websocket and the http with the same url? Because it seems that http://example.com/socket.io and ws://example.com/socket.io is generated by socket.io from this line

```
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
```

Are there any other workaround to fix this, or deploying my socket.io node js app in my apache server without proxypass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nevermind, I manage to get it working with `RewriteEngine` for the web socket (`ws://`)

This is my `000-default.conf` in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/socket.io          [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:3000/%1        [P,L]

ProxyPass /ChatSocket http://localhost:3000
ProxyPassReverse /ChatSocket http://localhost:3000
ProxyPass /socket.io http://localhost:3000/socket.io
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:3000/socket.io
```